# node.js search by file name

Tags: javascript, node.js, path

I have This program that prints a list of files in a given directory, filtered by the extension of the files. I need to change it to a program that searches for all files that contains a specified string (in the file name) also filtered by the extension of the files, under the current directory. Basically I need the first argument to be the file name instead directory path, and the directory path should be the current directory and not as an argument.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var dirPath = process.argv[2];  //directory path
var fileType = '.'+process.argv[3]; //file extension
var files = [];
fs.readdir(dirPath, function(err,list){
    if(err) throw err;
    for(var i=0; i<list.length; i++)
    {
        if(path.extname(list[i])===fileType)
        {
            console.log(list[i]); //print the file
            files.push(list[i]); //store the file name into the array files
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
try this code   
var fs = require('fs');
    var path = require('path');
    var filename = '.'+process.argv[1]; //file extension
    var fileType = '.'+process.argv[2]; //file extension
    var files = [];
    fs.readdir(process.cwd(), function(err,list){
        if(err) throw err;
        for(var i=0; i<list.length; i++)
        {
            /*user your conditions AND/OR */
            if(path.extname(list[i])===fileType && list[i].indexOf(filename) != -1)
            {
                console.log(list[i]); //print the file
                files.push(list[i]); //store the file name into the array files
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using the glob package for this. Please see: https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob

Example:

```
var glob = require("glob")

// options is optional
glob("**/*.js", options, function (er, files) {
  // files is an array of filenames.
  // If the `nonull` option is set, and nothing
  // was found, then files is ["**/*.js"]
  // er is an error object or null.
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **__dirname** for current directory path

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var dirPath = __dirname;//process.argv[2];  //directory path
var fileType = '.'+process.argv[2]; //file extension
var files = [];
fs.readdir(dirPath, function(err,list){
    if(err) throw err;
    for(var i=0; i<list.length; i++)
    {
        if(path.extname(list[i])===fileType)
        {
            console.log(list[i]); //print the file
            files.push(list[i]); //store the file name into the array files
        }
    }
});
```